# Rendering .ui file of "Processing Provider" plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, interface

I have a plugin built by Processing Provider template. I want to open it into Qt designer and change appearance of elements. As I understand I need .ui file for this purpose. However Processing Provider doesn't generate such file. Is there a solution for this problem?